# Why am I getting a child compiling error on React.js?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to learn react.js and I don't have a lot of experience in dealing with backend stuff (I used the create-react-app package). It's the first time I've set up a dev environment. This was working perfectly last night, and now, loading up the mac today I get this:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoZYN.png)

[image: Project directory]

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <link href="./style.css">
  <head>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="./src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the index.js:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

import App from "./App.js"


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

and the App.js:

```
import React from "react"

import Nav from "./Nav.js"
import MainContent from "./MainContent.js"
import Footer from "./Footer.js"

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Nav />
            <MainContent />
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

And then the three function files:

```
import React from "react"

function Nav() {
    return (
        <div>
            <header className="navbar">This is the header</header>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Nav
```

.

```
import React from "react"

function MainContent() {
    return (
        <div>
            <main className="main">This is the body of the page.</main>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MainContent
```

.

```
import React from "react"


function Footer() {
    return (
        <footer>
            <h3 className="footer">This is my footer element</h3>
        </footer>
    )
}

export default Footer
```

Comment: Can you show your project directory sctructure? Normally **index.html** is located in the **public** folder.

Comment: I've added that now

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).